# GAM smooths interaction differences - calculate p value using mgcv and gratia 0.6

Tags: r, interaction, mgcv

I am using the useful gratia package by Gavin Simpson to extract the difference in two smooths for two different levels of a factor variable. The smooths are generated by the wonderful mgcv package. For example

```
library(mgcv)

library(gratia)

m1 <- gam(outcome ~ s(dep_var, by = fact_var) + fact_var, data = my.data)

diff1 <- difference_smooths(m1, smooth = "s(dep_var)")

draw(diff1)
```

This give me a graph of the difference between the two smooths for each level of the "by" variable in the `gam()` call. The graph has a shaded 95% credible interval (CI) for the difference.
Statistical significance, or areas of statistical significance at the 0.05 level, is assessed by whether or where the y = 0 line crosses the CI, where the y axis represents the difference between the smooths.

Here is an example from Gavin's site where the "by" factor variable had 3 levels.

[image]

The differences are clearly statistically significant (at 0.05) over nearly all of the graphs.

Here is another example I have generated using a "by" variable with 2 levels.

[image]

The difference in my example is clearly not statistically significant anywhere.

In the `mgcv` package, an approximate p value is outputted for a smooth fit that tests the null hypothesis that the coefficients are all = 0, based on a chi square test.

My question is, can anyone suggest a way of calculating a p value that similarly assesses the difference between the two smooths instead of solely relying on graphical evidence?

The output from `difference_smooths()` is a data frame with differences between the smooth functions at 100 points in the range of the smoothed variable, the standard error for the difference and the upper and lower limits of the CI.

Here is a link to the release of gratia 0.4 that explains the `difference_smooths()` function
[enter link description here](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2020/05/31/new-gratia-release/)

but gratia is now at version 0.6
[enter link description here](https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/)

Thanks in advance for taking the time to consider this.

Don

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting a p value for the interaction between the by factor variables is to manipulate the `difference_smooths()` function by activating the `ci_level` option. Default is 0.95. The `ci_level` can be manipulated to find a level where the y = 0 is no longer within the CI bands. If for example this occurred when `ci_level = my_level`, the p value for testing the hypothesis that the difference is zero everywhere would be 1 - my_level.

This is not totally satisfactory. For example, it would take a little manual experimentation and it may be difficult to discern accurately when zero drops out of the CI. Although, a function could be written to search the accompanying data frame that is outputted with `difference_smooths()` as the `ci_level` is varied. This is not totally satisfactory either because the detection of a non-zero CI would be dependent on the 100 points chosen by `difference_smooths()` to assess the difference between the two curves. Then again, the standard errors are approximate for a GAM using `mgcv`, so that shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Here is a graph where the zero first drops out of the CI.

[image]

Zero dropped out at `ci_level = 0.88` and was still in the interval at `ci_level = 0.89`. So an approxiamte p value would be 1 - 0.88 = 0.12.

Can anyone think of a better way?

**Reply to Gavin Simpson's comments Feb 19**

Thanks very much Gavin for taking the time to make your comments.
I am not sure if using the criterion, >= 0 (for negative diffs), is a good way to go. Because of the draws from the posterior, there is likely to be many diffs that meet this criterion. I am interpreting your criterion as sample the posterior distribution and count how many differences meet the criterion, calculate the percentage and that is the p value. Correct me if I have misunderstood. Using this approach, I consistently got p values at around 0.45 - 0.5 for different gam models, even when it was clear the difference in the smooths should be statistically significant, at least at p = 0.05, because the confidence band around the smooth did not contain zero at a number of points.

Instead, I was thinking perhaps it would be better to compare the means of the posterior distribution of each of the diffs. For example

```
    # get coefficients for the by smooths
    coeff.level1  <-   coef(gam.model1)[31:38]
    coeff.level0  <-   coef(gam.model1)[23:30]
    # these indices are specific to my multi-variable gam.model1
    # in my case 8 coefficients per smooth
    
    # get posterior coefficients variances for the by smooths' coefficients
    vp_level1 <-  gam.model1$Vp[31:38, 31:38]
    vp_level0 <-  gam.model1$Vp[23:30, 23:30]
    
    
       #run the simulation to get the distribution of each 
       #difference coefficient using the joint variance
    
           library(MASS)

           no.draws = 1000
            sim <- mvrnorm(n = no.draws, (coeff.level1 - coeff.level0),
                          (vp_level1 + vp_level0))
    
    # sim is a no.draws X no. of coefficients (8 in my case) matrix
    
    # put the results into a data.frame. 
    
    y.group <- data.frame(y = as.vector(sim), 
               group = c(rep(1,no.draws), rep(2,no.draws), 
                         rep(3,no.draws), rep(4,no.draws), 
                         rep(5,no.draws), rep(6,no.draws), 
                         rep(7,no.draws), rep(8,no.draws)) )
    
    
    # y has the differences sampled from their posterior distributions.
    # group is just a grouping name for the 8 sets of differences,
    # (one set for each difference in coefficients)
    
    # compare means with a linear regression
    
        lm.test <- lm(y ~ as.factor(group), data = y.group)
        summary(lm.test)
    
    # The p value for the F statistic tells you how 
    # compatible the data are with the null hypothesis that
    # all the group means are equal to each other. 
    # Same F statistic and p value from   
    anova(lm.test)
```

One could argue that if all coefficients are not equal to each other then they all can't be equal to zero but that isn't what we want here.
The basis of the smooth tests of fit given by `summary(mgcv::gam.model1)`
is a joint test of all coefficients == 0. This would be from a type of likelihood ratio test where model fit with and without a term are compared.

I would appreciate some ideas how to do this with the difference between two smooths.

Now that I got this far, I had a rethink of your original suggestion of using the criterion, >= 0 (for negative diffs). I reinterpreted this as meaning for each simulated coefficient difference distribution (in my case 8), count when this occurs and make a table where each row (my case, 8) is for one of these distributions with two columns holding this count and (number of simulation draws minus count), Then on this table run a chi square test. When I did this, I got a very low p value when I believe I shouldn't have as 0 was well within the smooth difference CI across almost all the levels of the exposure. Maybe I am still misunderstanding your suggestion.

**Follow up thought Feb 24**

In a follow up thought, we could create a variable that represents the interaction between the by factor and continuous variable

```
    library(dplyr)
my.dat <- my.dat %>% mutate(interact.var = 
                    ifelse(factor.2levels == "yes", 1, 0)*cont.var)
```

Here I am assuming that factor.2levels has the levels ("no", "yes"), and "no" is the reference level. The `ifelse` function creates a dummy variable which is multiplied by the continuous variable to generate the interactive variable.

Then we place this interactive variable in the GAM and get the usual statistical test for fit, that is, testing all the coefficients == 0.

Comment: I'm not sure that works; it depends on the coverage properties of the differences of smooths. If they are closer to pointwise, then this won't work because you are committing a multiple testing error. If they are or are close to the across-the-function intervals of Nychka/Marra -&-Wood then this might work on average as those intervals have approximately the right correct coverage.

Comment: Using simultaneous intervals for the difference would likely be better. Also you could do this using posterior simulation; for each draw from the posterior of the 2 smooths, difference the smooths, then calculate what proportion of the posterior are >= 0 (for negative diffs) or <= 0 (for positive diffs)

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thanks very much Gavin for your comments. I have replied via adding to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

@GavinSimpson actually posted a method of how to get the difference between two smooths and assess its statistical significance [here](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/12/14/difference-splines-ii/) in 2017. Thanks to Matteo Fasiolo for pointing me in that direction.

In that approach, the by variable is converted to an ordered categorical variable which causes `mgcv::gam` to produce difference smooths in comparison to the reference level. Statistical significance for the difference smooths is then tested in the usual way with the `summary` command for the gam model.

However, and correct me if I have misunderstood, the ordered factor approach causes the smooth for the main effect to now be the smooth for the reference level of the ordered factor.

The approach I suggested, see the main post under the heading, **Follow up thought Feb 24**, where the interaction variable is created, gives an almost identical result for the p value for the difference smooth but does not change the smooth for the main effect. It also does not change the intercept and the linear term for the by categorical variable which also both changed with the ordered variable approach.